# Which wifi security setting is correct?

Tags: wpa2

I have six choices on my HP laptop WiFi security tab.

How do I know which one to choose? Which is best?

Comment: Whichever one your access point is using? i'm not sure you understand what those options mean.

Comment: Why don't you list those options.

Answer (score 3):

Those options are not for choosing. They have to match with the security type your Wi-Fi access point uses. If your router uses WPA you have to use WPA. If it uses WEP , you have to use WEP. If you were to talk to someone in Spanish, but they only understand German, you wouldn't have much conversation, right ? Same idea here.

Unless you're doing anything advanced or special (like setting static IP), you don't have to change that by hand - when you connect to access point, computer and router will agree on those settings. If you were to modify your router settings, then you would have to edit your connection on Ubuntu as well, although even then you can simply delete the connection info ( which works like "Forget this network" option on Android ) and reconnect again - the settings will be stored automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Your clients (eg computers, mobile devices) need to use the same security as the wireless access point/router uses.

The best security for your wireless access point or router will be a WPA based security, preferably WPA2-PSK (AES).  The older WPA versions prior to WPA2 are not as secure, whereas WEP is considered *VERY INSECURE*.

There are two flavours of WPA: WPA-Personal (also known as WPA-PSK) and WPA-Enterprise.  These don't really represent two different levels of security but two different feature sets: WPA-Enterprise is useful for when you need separate people with separate accounts and passwords, and you want the ability to revoke access on a per-account basis.  Authentication is handled by a special server.  By contrast, on WPA-PSK everybody just uses the same passphrase.  It's simpler and suitable for use at home on simple hardware.